# How does a single Shockwave flash plugin process control all flash content in Chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, plugins, chromium, flash-player

Is there a method to find which thread of flash is controlling which flash content?
My aim is to find per tab bandwidth statistics.